# Add functions to existing states' onEnter in SimpleStateManager and have them execute

Tags: javascript

I'm using [Simple State Manager](https://github.com/SimpleStateManager/SimpleStateManager) and setting up a set of global states to match against project wide, using Bootstrap breakpoints. I'm doing this so that we have consistent use of state names, and can easily tap into pre-defined breakpoints.

I'm then trying to work out a way to add functionality to a state change match on both page load and later using the onEnter handler. Basically, we have page specific javascript that will add its own functions when a media query is matched.

I've almost got it working; my problem is that I can either get the function to run on page load, or on state match, but not both.

Here's the code setting up the media query states matching our Bootstrap breakpoints, as well as defining the media queries for SimpleStateManager:

```
// bootstrap variables
var screenMax = 479,
    screenXsMin=480,
    screenSmMin=768,
    screenMdMin=992,
    screenLgMin=1200,
    screenXsMax=(screenSmMin - 1),
    screenSmMax=(screenMdMin - 1),
    screenMdMax=(screenLgMin - 1);

// Set up strings for queries. These can be used when adding states in custom.js,
var mqScreenMax= 'only screen and (max-width:'+screenMax+'px)',
// Set up an xs min, max, and only
    mqXsMin= 'only screen and (min-width:'+screenXsMin+'px)',
    mqXsMax= 'only screen and (max-width:'+screenXsMax+'px)',
    //mqXsOnly= 'only screen and (min-width:'+screenXsMin+'px) and (max-width:'+screenXsMax+'px)',
// set up a sm min max and only
    mqSmMin= 'only screen and (min-width:'+screenSmMin+'px)',
    mqSmMax= 'only screen and (max-width:'+screenSmMax+'px)',
    //mqSmOnly= 'only screen and (min-width:'+screenSmMin+'px) and (max-width:'+screenSmMax+'px)',
// set up a md min max and only
    mqMdMin= 'only screen and (min-width:'+screenMdMin+'px)',
    mqMdMax= 'only screen and (max-width:'+screenMdMax+'px)',
    //mqMdOnly= 'only screen and (min-width:'+screenMdMin+'px) and (max-width:'+screenMdMax+'px)',
// finalize with a large min
    mqLgMin= 'only screen and (min-width:'+screenLgMin+'px)';

// Add the different states we can test against
ssm.addStates([
    {
        id: 'scr-max',
        query: mqScreenMax
    },
    {
        id: 'xs-min',
        query: mqXsMin
    },
    {
        id: 'xs-max',
        query: mqXsMax
    },
    {
        id: 'sm-min',
        query: mqSmMin
    },
    {
        id: 'sm-max',
        query: mqSmMax
    },
    {
        id: 'md-min',
        query: mqMdMin
    },
    {
        id: 'md-max',
        query: mqMdMax
    },
    {
        id: 'lg-min',
        query: mqLgMin
    }
]);
```

On a specific page, I want to add some functionality when we match our "sm-min" media query:

```
ssm.getState('sm-min').options.onEnter.push(
    function() {
        // do stuff
    }
);
```

This works if I resize the screen down and back up, triggering the onEnter private function. However, it doesn't work on page load, whereas if I had defined that onEnter function in my initial ssm.addStates() above, it would. I'm assuming this is because I'm adding the function in AFTER SSM has instantiated, and thus it isn't running. So, to get around that, I tried forcing it to run as a IIFE:

```
ssm.getState('sm-min').options.onEnter.push(
    (function() {
        // do stuff
    })()
);
```

This then works as expected, running immediately, but never runs again on the next match.

I have also attempted to add both a function and an IIFE and couldn't get that to work. (Pretty sure that isn't valid array code, or use of an array):

```
ssm.getState('sm-min').options.onEnter.push([
    (function() {
        // do stuff
    }()),
    function() {
        // do stuff
    }
]);
```

I haven't figured out how to force SSM to re-execute itself after adding the onEnter function using the push(); the [documentation](http://www.simplestatemanager.com/api.html) doesn't cover that (and is a bit out of date). I dug around inside the src/ssm.js but I think my handle of javascript isn't up to par to figure out how to force it to enterState or re-init.

Anyone know how to add functionality and have it execute and continue to execute?

Comment: I don't know `ssm`, but are you sure that you should be pushing an array onto `onEnter`? I would imagine this: `ssm.getState('sm-min').options.onEnter.push(function () {...});`

Comment: Argh good catch, that array was there after also trying to pass both an IIFE and a regular function. The onEnter functions are stored as arrays, though. Anyway, updated that and added a third example.